# Disabling a Slider in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, slider, apple-watch

So far, I know how to disable a button in swift. In my Apple Watch program I want to disable the slider as well. So, when the + and - buttons are pressed, nothing should happen. Is there any way to do such a thing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The internal + and - buttons always increment and decrement a value.

If you don't want the value to be incremented or decremented, add them as ordinary buttons and set their text to + and -.

Else, you can use the internal ones.